# Using the Arcade Split function to create a list element in ArcGIS Dashboard

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I am making a dashboard in ArcGIS Online. (see figure)

[image: dashboard view, with a map on the left, list in the middle and bar diagram on the right]

I want to create a list for users to select their biomass of interest and use them as a filter for the diagrams on the right. The current names in the list are ugly (for lack of a better word). I want to remove everything contained in brackets.
For this purpose, I used Arcade's Split() function as follows:

`Split(Text($datapoint["Nom_biomasse"])," (",1)[0]`

However, the result is still the exact same as `$datapoint["Nom_biomasse"]` (the field containing the biomass names) on its own.

Is there something I am doing wrong or is this just something that cannot be done with dashboard lists?

It seems the Split() function inside the expression works fine. However, I am unable to reference it in the list itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. May this serve as an illustration to the [ArcGIS online help](https://doc.arcgis.com/fr/dashboards/create-and-share/advanced-formatting.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_69E222FC0A7C48CD8538F9087969ACAC).

When enabling advanced formatting, there is a sample code available. My mistake was to ignore this sample code and write my expression from scratch.
Following the sample structure, here is my current Arcade expression:

```
return {
  textColor: '',
  backgroundColor: '',
  separatorColor:'',
  selectionColor: '',
  selectionTextColor: '',
  attributes: {
        attribute2: Split($datapoint["Nom_biomasse"], " (")[0]
  }
}
```

The `attribute2` can then be referenced in the list with the following expression:

```
{expression/attribute2}
```

(see figure)
[image]